# Wordpress - Change image in article but keep attributes

Tags: php, wordpress

like the topic says: Is there a way to change an image in an existing wordpress article while keeping all the defined attriutes for that image like description and so on? Maybe a plugin?

Best Regards,

Stephan S.

Comment: You are looking for an existing plugin or "how to" write your own? Is there a correlation between the old and new image (ie.: a thumbnail) or something provided by a user?

Comment: Well, an existing plugin would be the best of course- But if there is no existing plugin I'll write my own. And no, there would be no correlation. My idea how this should work is like:User edits an image inside an article and just choses a new image while keeping all other attributes.

Comment: Clicking Edit Image > Advanced Settings you can already change the URL manually and all the other attributes are kept.

Comment: Well yes but that's just if the user knows the url for the picture in the media library or wants to supply an external url. But there is no option to just upload a new image. That's what I mean. Sorry that I didn't mention this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [Enable Media Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/enable-media-replace/) should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately this only enables replacing images in the media library and not in the article.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see this detail and I didn't try it on my own WordPress.  This is such a simple problem, there HAS to be a solution :)

Comment: Yeah, but I just can't find any :(

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the plugin Enable Media Replace (as suggested by emartel), and it seems that it now also updates posts that include the affected image or use it as a featured image.
The preview (just after uploading) still shows the old image, but later in the library it seems to get replaced and it seems to work.